# Why is org.joda.time.LocalDate a date without a timezone?

Tags: date, time, timestamp, jodatime

I think the name `org.joda.time.LocalDate` is kind of confusing. The documentation says:

> `LocalDate` is an immutable datetime class representing a date without a time zone.

In comparison `org.joda.time.DateTime` says:

> A `DateTime` calculates its fields with respect to a time zone.

I am always confusing those two so I hope somebody can tell me why those names are supposed to make sense.

---

Here is my intuition: A **local** date or time object would represent a point in time but with regards to a *location*. Hence it should contain the time zone information since the time zone also gives you some sort of *location* information. In any case you know a little more about somebodies location than without that time zone.

A date-time, at least as it sounds like, should only represent a date and a time. In this sense it is just the `long` value since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970.

---

So why is it actually the other way around? This naming bugs me every time I have something to do with time stamps. Can somebody explain?

**Update:**

Interesting link posted by a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2491410/meno-hochschild): https://sourceforge.net/p/threeten/mailman/message/29962542/

Comment: I feel sorry for you. You are by far not the only one who is confused about the naming, The bank Credit Suisse had also suggested to choose other clearer names (`PlainDate` etc.) earlier during the development of the JSR-310, see this [mailing](https://sourceforge.net/p/threeten/mailman/message/29962542/). But the JSR-310-team has not taken this suggestion into account, maybe they were just totally unwilling to change their naming due to long naming traditions inherited by Joda-Time.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Thanks for that link. Feels good to know it's not just me who feels that way - I felt stupid for confusing those again and again ^^ I added your link to my question and "*cited*" you if that's okay. :) I call you "user" in case you ever change your *displayname* like I did. ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Terminology

Your intuition is the opposite of the terminology used by both Joda-Time and java.time.

Both frameworks have a class named `LocalDate` to represent a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. The ”local“ means ”could be any locality, not any particular locality“.

The ”Local…“ classes are just a rough idea of a time. They are not on the timeline. They have no real meaning until you apply a time zone or offset-from-UTC to get actual moments on the timeline. When you see ”Local“ think: ”this value does not really make sense until we apply a time zone“.

For example, we say that Christmas is on 2016-12-25 this year. But the date is not the same around the world at any given moment. A new day dawns earlier in Paris than in Montréal for example. So to get the moment when Christmas starts in Paris, you must apply the `Europe/Paris` time zone and get the first moment of that day. That first moment will be represented by `DateTime` in Joda-Time and by `ZonedDateTime` (or `OffsetDateTime`) in java.time.

For example, in java.time:

```
LocalDate xmas2016 = LocalDate.of( 2016 , 12 , 25 );
ZonedDateTime xmas2016FirstMomentMontreal = xmas2016.atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) );
```

## java.time

In the java.time framework, a moment on the timeline in UTC is represented by the `Instant` class.

```
Instant now = Instant.now();
```

Apply a time zone, `ZoneId`, to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

If all you have is an offset-from-UTC rather than a full time zone, than use `OffsetDateTime` rather than `ZonedDateTime`.

You can think of this way:

> Instant + ZoneId -> ZonedDateTime
>
> Instant + ZoneOffset ->OffsetDateTime

This information has been covered many hundreds of times already on StackOverflow. Please search to learn more and see many pieces of example code.

Comment: Why does it feel so counter intuitive to me. I mean *Local* really suggests that there is some "locality" information contained which can only mean that I *have* the time zone with it. Having only the `long` value is for me the definition of having only a *rough* idea of a time. Having no information about somebodies locality. So it's just a date and a time without any further specification. I really don't understand why the naming is the other way around. :D

Comment: The naming is certainly counter-intuitive. But can you devise better names? I cannot. And anyways, the naming is set in the concrete of published API now. So, we need just flip our minds to the opposite of our intuition: ”Local…“ means *any* locality, none in particular.

Comment: Tip: When in doubt, do not use the Locals. In common business apps we usually care about the actual moment an invoice was received, a check written, an employee hired, or a contract signed. So use a `ZonedDateTime` for those.

Comment: My question actually rose from [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35538854/what-are-the-timestamp-and-date-equivalents-in-jodatime). I am having a `Shop` which has a time zone defined. I am thinking about storing e-g. the opening hours as `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` since the information is actually stored in the table `Shop`. But I am not sure if I should do that ^^

Comment: SQL’s `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` is the matching type for Java’s `LocalDateTime`. You should almost [never use it](http://justatheory.com/computers/databases/postgresql/use-timestamptz.html). It has no real meaning until you apply a time zone. Use it only for something like ”Christmas this year starts on 2016-12-25 00:00:00.0“. No time zone, no meaning, not a moment on the timeline.

Comment: For a check written, employee hired, etc. I should have said use an `Instant`. Generally use `Instant` in your business logic, logging, data storage, serialization, XML/JSON, and such. You only need a `ZonedDateTime` for presentation to the user.

Comment: Okay I think now I am confused ^^ `Instant` means basically *always UTC*, right? So e.g. if I store the date of an offer I use `TIMEZONEZ` in my database and `DateTime` as mapping for the web server, right? When do I use `Instant`?

Comment: `DateTime` is Joda-Time, but I've been referring to java.time. The two frameworks are similar, indeed one inspiring the other, but they are different. Use Joda-Time only if stuck in Java 7 or earlier. Let's focus on java.time where `java.time.Instant` maps to `java.sql.Timestamp` which converts to UTC any value retrieved from SQL’s `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`. In the case of Postgres that data type is already stored in UTC after using any specified offset or time zone info passed with inputs; that passed offset/zone is dropped after  adjustment to UTC. The offset/zone was *used* not retained.